# Datatable columns and rows are in a wrong order

Tags: sql, vb.net, epplus

I'm trying to place some information from a spreadsheet using EPPLUS into a databale which will be exported to sql server afterwards.
The Problem I am having is that when I create the datatable columns, and then start inserting the rows, the end result shows a misalignment between row information and column headings. 
Here is the code:

```
    Sub ConvertPackage2DT()

        Dim FILENAME As String = "C:\Data.xlsx"

        Dim flInfo As New FileInfo(FILENAME)

        _package = New ExcelPackage(flInfo) 'load the excel file

        Dim strSheetName As String = "Radiology"

        Dim Conn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Data Source=dwsqlserver1\instance3;Initial Catalog=LocalDatasets_Dev;Integrated Security=True") 'connection to server end
        Dim DTExport As New DataTable


        If Not IsNothing(_package) Then

            Dim _workbook As ExcelWorkbook = _package.Workbook
            Dim _sheets As ExcelWorksheets = _workbook.Worksheets
            Dim sh As ExcelWorksheet = _sheets.Item(strSheetName)


            If _package.Workbook.Worksheets.Count <> 0 Then

                For Each _sheet In _sheets
                    Dim SHEET_NAME As String = _sheet.Name
                    Dim tbl As New DataTable
                    Dim hasHeader = True ' adjust accordingly '



                    For ColNum = 1 To sh.Dimension.End.Column
                        tbl.Columns.Add(sh.Cells(1, ColNum).Value)
                    Next
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(tbl.Columns.Count)

                For rowNum = 2 To sh.Dimension.End.Row

                    Dim v(sh.Dimension.End.Column - 1) As Object
                    For X = 0 To sh.Dimension.End.Column - 2
                        v(X) = sh.Cells(rowNum, X + 1).Value
                    Next
                    tbl.Rows.Add(v)

                    'tbl.Rows.Add(wsRow.Select(Function(cell) cell.Text).ToArray)
                Next



                Conn.Open()

                Using bulkcopy As SqlBulkCopy = New SqlBulkCopy(Conn)
                    bulkcopy.DestinationTableName = "[LocalDatasets_Dev].[dbo].[" & GetNewTableName(6) & "]"
                    bulkcopy.WriteToServer(tbl)
                End Using

                Conn.Close()
                MsgBox("Complete")
                Exit Sub
                Next _sheet
            End If
        End If
    End Sub


End Module
```

Can anyone help? Thank you kindly

Comment: Do you have multiple sheets and do all of your sheets have the same layout? As is, if you have multiple sheets, it will add new columns each time it finds a new sheet and then add the data to the already existing columns, even if they are not the same.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful hint but if you look at the code it does exit at the end of the 'next sheet' loop once it starts reading through the correct one. So it must be some other problem. The issue is why, when i add the columns it has to jumble them up in another order afterwards. I'm trying to work out a away of getting the columns to be output the same way they are read in, as is the case with the Row number loop

Comment: Not feeling too bright right now, but this looks wrong "For X = 0 To sh.Dimension.End.Column - 2" - should that not be -1 instead?

Comment: Hi Paddy, No theres a reason for that as the array starts from 0, anyway i can sort that out no probs. Just trying to work out this issue with the column adjustment to the correct rows.

Comment: The code editor on this site is a real pain - tried evrything for it to display correctly with indents etc. :(